# error reading .DBF file on c#

Tags: c#, sql, dbf

dbf file and upload into a sql table  here is my code

```
public void prueba()
{
    String strConnection = "Data Source=192.168.87.15;" 
                         + "Initial Catalog=indarneg;" 
                         + "User id=sa;" 
                         + "Password=;";
    //file upload path
    string path = "C:\\Maquina_virtual\\promociones\\18\\";

    string dbfConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" 
        + path + ";Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=Admin;Password=;";

    OleDbConnection dbfConnection = new OleDbConnection(dbfConnectionString);
    //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from dbf
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [ART]", dbfConnection);
    dbfConnection.Open();
    OleDbDataReader dReader;
    dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection);
    //Give your Destination table name
    sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "artdbf";
    sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
    dbfConnection.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("DONE");
}
```

but i get error" Unexpected Error from External Database Driver (8961) " the  .dbf file is 279 megabytes

Comment: [link]https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321003

Comment: I already  follow the instructions with no luck :(

Comment: Can you explain what kind of db file is please(access,sql,my sql) etc.
or go to this page http://www.connectionstrings.com/ maybe you can find the connection string to your db.

Comment: Have you considered downloading Microsoft's Visual FoxPro driver which can read DBF files vs the jet engine.  The connection process is the same (except change the provier to VFPOleDB.1) via pointing to the path where the tables exist, and still uses OleDB as you have.